Using Gaussian decomposition in numerical algorithm for 1D Schrodinger equation
I've been working on this as a small hobby side project to my main graduate work in a different area, so please excuse any lack of knowledge.
I've been developing a program for simulating an arbitrary initial 1D wave function, by numerically integrating the 1D Schrodinger equation, using a method that I hadn't seen done before. Since the Schrodinger equation is linear for sums of wave functions, the idea is to decompose the wave function into a sum of simple Gaussian components, and then individually integrate each Gaussian along the time step.
My reasoning is that, for each Gaussian wave function, the kinetic energy component of the Schrodinger equation can be replaced with a factor added to the potential function, ie
\begin{align}
i\frac{\Delta\psi_n}{\Delta t}&=\frac{-1}{2m}\frac{d^2}{dx^2}e^{-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2\sigma^2}}+V(x)e^{-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\\
&=\left(-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2m\sigma^4}+\frac{1}{2m\sigma^2}+V(x)\right)e^{-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\\
&=V_\ast(x)e^{-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2\sigma^2}}
\end{align}
Then, for each Gaussian, the Schrodinger equation is reduced to a product of this modified potential with the Gaussian.
If the modified potential can be reasonably expressed as a Taylor series at the center of the Gaussian, then the result of this product requires minimal computation during simulation, as the products of any Gaussian with each component of the Taylor series centered on that Gaussian can be pre-computed (as a sum of Gaussians) for a generic Gaussian and then scaled appropriately, ie
$$f_1(x)=x e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}=\textrm{ some sum of Gaussians}$$
$$f_2(x)=\frac{x^2}{2} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}=\textrm{ some sum of Gaussians}$$
$$\cdots$$
\begin{align}
i\frac{\Delta\psi_n}{\Delta t}&=V_\ast(x) e^{-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\\
&=\left(V_\ast(x_0)+(x-x_0)V'_\ast(x_0)+\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2} V''_\ast(x_0) \cdots\right) e^{-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\\
& = V_\ast(x_0) e^{-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{2\sigma^2}} + V'_\ast(x_0) \sigma f_1\left(\frac{x-x_0}{\sigma}\right) + V''_\ast(x_0) \sigma^2 f_2\left(\frac{x-x_0}{\sigma})\right) \cdots 
\end{align}
Thus the simulation at each time step remains completely in the Gaussian domain.
This does result in exponentially more Gaussians in the sum after each time step, so in-between each time step, the algorithm fits a smaller number of Gaussians to the result while staying below a threshold tolerance for error from the original larger Gaussian sum.
As I had hoped, the integration portion of the algorithm is almost instant to simulate each timestep, with the grand majority of the time spent in-between time steps, fitting the reduced number of gaussians, using a pretty bare bones implementation of gradient descent to minimize the error.
I am still working on improving the fitting time, but I was curious whether there were any other examples of this kind of "Gaussian-decomposition" approach that anyone could share? It would be very helpful to see if there are any techniques/methods that other people have used to speed up the process, improve precision, etc.
As far as I can tell, this method should also generalize to 2 or 3 dimensions, and I'd love to try modifying my program to do so, but the fitting is slow at 1D, so I can't imagine it would be reasonable at higher dimensions, without some kind of improved method.
